# BulletSpan not working

Tags: android, spannable

I'm trying to insert a BulletSpan into a SpannableStringBuilder, but the BulletSpan never appears.

```
private void insertBulletSpan(SpannableStringBuilder spannable) {
    Matcher matcher = bulletPattern.matcher(spannable);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        boolean set = true;
        for (BulletSpan span : spannable.getSpans(matcher.start(),
                matcher.end(), BulletSpan.class))
            if (spannable.getSpanStart(span) >= matcher.start()
                    && spannable.getSpanEnd(span) <= matcher.end())
                spannable.removeSpan(span);
            else {
                set = false;
                break;
            }
        if (set) {
            spannable.setSpan(new BulletSpan(),
                    matcher.start(), matcher.end(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

where bulletPattern:

```
bulletPattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("|b|"));
```

so actually I want to replace every occurrence of "|b|" with a BulletSpan. The method to set the span is called, I verified that, but the text still contains all the |b|.
I use exactly the same code snippet with ImageSpans, URLSpans and UnderlineSpans to replace similar occurrences. They work just fine.

Comment: try a simple case when you call ss.setSpan(bs, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); vs ss.setSpan(bs, 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: ss.setSpan(bs, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); works, the bullets are drawn at the beginning, but ss.setSpan(bs, 1, 2, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); doesn't do anything - what does this tell me now?

Comment: it tells you that bullet can be set only on the begining of the line, for example: for "qwe\nrty" you can use start=4 end=5, in your case just use ImageSpan with a dot as an image or use a ReplacementSpan for more flexible usage

Comment: Ah, thank you. In my case I had already added an indent, removing this made it work.

Comment: indent? what indent? you mean a space?

Comment: My text looked like "   |b| xyz". Changing it "|b| xyz" made it work I mean.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same challenge and it turns out a BulletSpan will only show when `it's starting point` is set to the `beginning of a (new) line`.
In my case after a "\r\n" pair.

Comment: This is correct and alluded to in the documentation: `"BulletSpans must be attached from the first character to the last character of a single paragraph, otherwise the bullet point will not be displayed but the first paragraph encountered will have a leading margin."` Note that it's sufficient to precede each character sequence to be bulleted with a `\n`. It doesn't need to be `\r\n`.